# Test with Postman look for a specific item in an array of objects in a response

Tags: javascript, postman, http-get

I have a response with the following body, an array.
I want to check that we have an item and only one with value IsPrimary true and  salePerson of value 'Chuck Norris'.

```
[
{
    "districtName": "Austria",
    "storeName": "Store6",
    "salePerson": "sdfgh",
    "isPrimary": false
},
{
    "districtName": "Austria",
    "storeName": "Store6",
    "salePerson": "dfsd",
    "isPrimary": false
},
{
    "districtName": "Austria",
    "storeName": "Store6",
    "salePerson": "Chuck Norris",
    "isPrimary": true
},
{
    "districtName": "Austria",
    "storeName": "Store6",
    "salePerson": "sdfgh",
    "isPrimary": false
}]
```

I tried with filtering it gave me error:

```
data =pm.response.body;
let object_to_find = { saleperson: 'Chuck Norris' };
let result2 = data.filter(function (value) {
    return value.id == object_to_find.id && value.name == object_to_find.name;
});
console.log(result2);
```

Error:

```
Couldn't evaluate the test script:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
```

Comment: Try to log data, what do you see?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul the body of the response as expected: [{"districtName":"Austria","storeName":"Store6","sal.....

Comment: I found an alternative solution:_.each(pm.response.json(), (item) => {
    if(item.salePerson === 'TestUpdate') {
        console.log(item);
     pm.expect(item.isPrimary=== true);  but I still do not understand why find() or filter() do not work.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered this on the Postman forums, so I'll include the same answer here.

Postman uses JavaScript under the hood, so this is more of a JavaScript question.

Here are two ways to test for those conditions using the JavaScript find function.

Option 1 searches on both conditions, and for the test you just need to check that the search is not undefined.

Option 2 searches for the name, and the test then checks if the isPrimary key = true in the returned object.

```js
const response = pm.response.json();

console.log(response);

pm.test('Sales person = Chuck Norris and isPrimary = true V1', () => {
    let searchV1 = response.find(obj => obj.salePerson === "Chuck Norris" && obj.isPrimary === true);
    console.log(searchV1);
    pm.expect(searchV1).to.not.be.undefined
})

pm.test('Sales person = Chuck Norris and isPrimary = true V2', () => {
    let searchV2 = response.find(obj => obj.salePerson === "Chuck Norris");
    console.log(searchV2);
    pm.expect(searchV2.isPrimary).to.be.true;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter the array based on a specific condition (in your case, looking for an item with salePerson as **'Chuck Norris'** and **isPrimary** as **true**), you can use the filter function as follows:

```
let data = pm.response.json();

let result = data. Filter(function(item) {
    return item.salePerson === 'Chuck Norris' && item.isPrimary === true;
});

console.log(result);
```

Also ensure that the response body (pm.response.body) is properly parsed into a JavaScript object using pm.response.json() before applying the filter function and confirm that the property names used for comparison (salePerson, isPrimary) match exactly with those in the response object.

Comment: It works! I had to clean the typos but it is exactly what I needed to include in my test. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Doraemon There are two improvements needed in this particular case.

- ***Response JSON is not properly formatted as array closing (square
  brace) is missing.***
- I tried to set up a mock server and tried to run
  the tests (thats where I found the array closing issue) and test can
  be improved as

`

```
pm.test("response to have object with specific values", function(){
    let object_to_find = { saleperson: 'Chuck Norris' };
    let result2 = pm.response.json().filter(function (value) {
        return value.id == object_to_find.id && value.name == object_to_find.name;
    });
    pm.expect(Array.isArray(result2)).to.eql(true);
    pm.expect(result2.length).to.greaterThan(0);
})
```

`

```
pm.test("response is array", function(){
    var data = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(Array.isArray(data)).toeql(true);
})
```

Attaching below the screenshot from local
[image: Test cases when array response is properly formatted]

Comment: The square bce was a typo, it is actually present in the real response. I tried your solution but it does not filter,  console.log(result2); still returns the whole starting array.